# (react-virtualized) Masonry dynamic column width, correct way clear cache

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

i have created a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/knQLm5NCog2Pvf1wWoMF/)

So, i have onResize event, and i think it a buggy, you can see timeout on `componentDidMount` what pushed new items to state, after 2s please scroll to bottom and try resize page, you will see blink on first time, and normal resize behavior after,
so what correct way to fix this blink or clear cache after resize?

Comment: link to plunker updated

Comment: Think it`s a bug of react-virtualized

Comment: Can be as solution, https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/917#issuecomment-354003062